# Is it possible to parse a string into ConsoleColor in C#

Tags: c#

```
string example = "Red"
if (example == "Red")
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.example;
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to set the background color of your console regarding the user's input (that input would be a text which represents a color)?

Comment: Yep! But ConsoleColor was just an example, I'd like to pass in a string like this for all kinds of things. Enum.Parse from below was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: ConsoleColor is an enum, but other Colors are not, and you can use `Color.FromName()`  Also notice that Enum.Parse is not that light, but i guess you are not concerned about performance :)

Comment: You guessed correctly. I'm making a text-based game, and so I'm assuming that my laptop can handle it even if it becomes really big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse value using Enum.Parse

```
string example = "Red"
  if (example == "Red")
  {    
    ConsoleColor consoleColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    try
    {
      consoleColor = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), example , true);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //Invalid color
    }

  Console.ForegroundColor = consoleColor ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
string example = "Red"
if (example == "Red")
{
     ConsoleColor consoleColor = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), "Red");
     Console.ForegroundColor = consoleColor;
}
```